# Custom hover popup in HTML/JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, hover

How would one be able to get a popup like the image below on hover of an element? I'm not sure what I should be adding in here apart from that I preferably don't want to use any other libraries apart from jquery. Please tell me if you need any code snippets or any more information!

[image]

Comment: @epascarello The only type of tooltips I can find are the basic black arrow ones that contain maybe a sentence or so

Comment: This is actually pretty easy to do.  create a div and set width and height. set display to hidden.  Then on hover set display to block

Comment: @DCR Yep, I'm trying to do that right now! I'll let you know if I get any more questions, thanks!

Comment: looks like that way won't work

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have said element above as a div on your page with an ID of 'cursor'. You can set the display value in your css to 'hidden', so it won't be displayed at first. When you hover over another element, you can trigger functions to display or hide said element:

```
<div id='hover-element' onmouseover='onMouseOver()' onmouseout='onMouseOut()'></div>
<div id=cursor'</div>
```

And then inside those functions:

```
function onMouseOver(element){
  document.getElementById('cursor').style.display = 'block';
}

function onMouseOut(element) {
  document.getElementById('cursor').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Try it :)